# Can't call Form element in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firefox, html-table

I'm having trouble not being too familiar with how to debug such problems. In my HTML lets say I have a form:

```
<form name="myForm" >
   <table>       
    <tr>
     <td>
       <input type="radio" name="myType" value="val" onclick="someFunc(this.value)"checked > stuff here
       <input type="radio" name="myType" value="val2" onclick="someFunc(this.value)"> stuff2 here
     </td>
    ..
</form>
```

In Javascript code, I am referencing this by:

```
myForm.myType[0].checked
```

In IE this works fine, but not in Firefox.  In Firefox I tried:

```
alert (myForm)
```

and also:

```
if (frmDateType == null)
{
    alert('null!');
}
else
{
    alert('not null!');
}
```

However, in both these cases Firefox doesn't even display an alert, it is basically doing nothing though it is fine in IE.  I have installed Firebug and it doesn't show any errors (or at least I can't find them).  So I'm not sure how to debug such an issue, why I don't see any errors and why Firefox doesn't like MyForm?  Any tips?

Comment: have you tried using the function getElementById? You would have to change your name attributes to id though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that anything with a name attribute will get a global variable that matches. This is non-standard behaviour.

You shouldn't be giving forms name attributes anyway, see the specification:

> Note. This attribute has been included for backwards compatibility. Applications should use the id attribute to identify elements.

So, first replace the name attribute with an id.

```
<form id="myForm">
```

And then you can access the form via:

```
document.getElementById('myForm')
```

or

```
document.forms.myForm
```

Comment: Ok yes I changed name to ID, and the full path works i.e document.forms.myForm vs myForm, thanks

Comment: `document.forms.myForm` works fine even without changing `name` to `id`. And HTML5 has no equivalent admonishment about using the `name` attribute for this purpose. It simply says "The name attribute represents the form's name within the forms collection. The value must not be the empty string, and the value must be unique amongst the form elements in the forms collection that it is in, if any."

Comment: Yes I think it was myForm vs document.forms.myForm

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as to why your Firefox is not displaying any alert; but you should check the Firefox Error Console.  Simply click in your address bar and press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on your keyboard to highlight the system menu; under Tools -> Web Developer -> Web Console you will be able to see all JavaScript, HTML and CSS errors encountered on the page at load time..

--

Please make sure you are referencing the form currectly in JavaScript:

```
myForm = document.getElementById("myForm"); // This requires the form to have an id.
```

Alternatively, you can reference the form using its name (not always works!)

```
myForm = document.forms.myForm;
```